# QR Code Scanner, scanning specific QR Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a QR Code Scanner built into my app using AVFoundation. It reads any QR Code that is presented to it. How can I have it read only a specific QR Code that I have created, and not every QR Code?

Comment: What does your specific QR code contain? String, telephone number etc ? Where Is your code?

Comment: My code is just linked with my email address. But for my app, it doesn't matter. The plan for my app is to reward the user with a point every time he/she scans the QR Code. With their points they can spend them on rewards that I also have in my app. But as of now, it reads every single QR Code. I want it to only read mine. Is that possible? @JSA986

Comment: What you could do is when the QR is scanned - check if the resulting string equals your email address.  If it does,  award a point

Comment: That's a great idea. Do you know how I could do that? As of now, whenever a QR Code is scanned my imageview presents a checkmark image @JSA986

Comment: Nevermind! I found it out, thanks a lot for the help. @JSA986